# mysql ORDER BY CASE in not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have the following query with ORDER BY CASE which is not returning expected results

```
SELECT 
c.* 
  FROM `ws_products` as c 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN c.stock>=0 THEN 1 
   WHEN (c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=1) THEN 2 
   WHEN (c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=0) THEN 3 END asc
```

I want to sort products with the following order

- First the products that have stock (c.stock>=0)
- Second the products    that dont have stock but have allow_backorder
  enabled (c.stock<=0 AND    c.allow_backorder=1)
- Last the products    that dont have stock and dont    have
  allow_backorder enabled    (c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=0)

I was expecting that the above query will do the work but its not

Do i have misunderstand CASE WHEN of mysql ?

Is my approach totally wrong ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Those having stock should be `c > 0` not `c >= 0`. There is a clash in your first and second condition.

Comment: @Madhur thanks its working now silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Madhur correctly jumped on the problem with his comment, but in addition to what he said, you can actually simplify the `CASE` expression a bit more:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM ws_products AS c
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN c.stock > 0 THEN 1
     WHEN c.allow_backorder = 1 THEN 2
     ELSE 3 END;
```

This works because if the stock is *not* greater than zero, then it must by definition by zero or less, so we don't need to explicitly check this in subsequent cases.  I assume that we can just bucket `allow_backorder = 0` in the `ELSE` condition, assuming that 0 and 1 are the only possible values there (and if not, then your original `CASE` expression should have had its own `ELSE` condition).

Comment: Good suggestions +1; but as of now this query (or even OP's query) cannot utilize any indexing. What if we define a composite index on `(allow_backorder, stock)` and write full blown case statement: `when c.allow_backorder IN (0,1) AND c.stock > 0 ...then...` ; `when c.allow_backorder = 1 AND c.stock <= 0` and so on..  Will MySQL be smart enough to use the indexing then ? Worth investigating !

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Correction to what you said: MySQL might not be able to use any indexing on the final _sorting_ step.  But in general, any index could be fair game for other parts of the query.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the comment of MadhurBhaiya help me solve me problem.Thsnks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN c.stock>0 THEN 1 
  WHEN (c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=1) THEN 2 
  WHEN (c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=0) THEN 3 END asc
```

I like this format (list of conditions) much more:

```
ORDER BY
  c.stock>0 DESC,
  c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=1 DESC,
  c.stock<=0 AND c.allow_backorder=0 DESC
```

And now we can optimize it (condition `c.stock>=0` used only once; assuming that c.allow_backorder is either `0` or `1`)

```
ORDER BY c.stock <= 0, c.allow_backorder DESC
```

Comment: I have corrected the logic; do check the comment below the question. Moreover, your query does have a side-effect that it is sorting by `allow_backorder` value even when product is "in-stock". OP does not need that.